# Docker composed webapp on Azure cannot be accessed

Tags: azure, flask, redis, docker-compose

My application is locally successfully built, run an accessible on http://localhost:5000 but not when it is deployed on Azure:

```
version: '3'
services:
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"

  web:
    build: .
    image: myappregistry.azurecr.io/myapp:latest
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
```

Composing it on Azure seems to work too:

```
2019-03-30 13:25:51.864 INFO  - Starting multi-container app, configuration = 
version: '3'
services:
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"

  web:
    build: .
    image: myappregistry.azurecr.io/myapp:latest
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"

2019-03-30 13:25:54.668 INFO  - Issuing docker pull redis:alpine
2019-03-30 13:25:57.223 INFO  - docker pull returned STDOUT>> alpine: Pulling from library/redis
Digest: sha256:a228f66132cd46a53fd818443c42458af5d6a3e1231df25184304b8e732e51c4
Status: Image is up to date for redis:alpine

2019-03-30 13:25:57.245 INFO  - Starting container for site
2019-03-30 13:25:57.247 INFO  - docker run -d -p 19446:6379 --name myapp003_redis_0 -e WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE=false -e WEBSITES_PORT=5000 -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=myapp003 -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=c04d15b1b0966eeeb73c65719c2b7ecac5f6223333efd04b1712f559b5660459 redis:alpine  

2019-03-30 13:25:57.249 INFO  - Logging is not enabled for this container.
Please use https://aka.ms/linux-diagnostics to enable logging to see container logs here.
2019-03-30 13:25:58.084 INFO  - Starting container for site
2019-03-30 13:25:58.086 INFO  - docker run -d -p 0:5000 --name myapp003_web_0 -e WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE=false -e WEBSITES_PORT=5000 -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=myapp003 -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=c04d15b1b0966eeeb73c65719c2b7ecac5f6223333efd04b1712f559b5660459 myappregistry.azurecr.io/myapp:latest  

2019-03-30 13:25:58.088 INFO  - Logging is not enabled for this container.
Please use https://aka.ms/linux-diagnostics to enable logging to see container logs here.
```

However, accessing it on https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/ fails with "502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server."

Note, in the Azure webapp "Application Settings" I set the value

```
WEBSITES_PORT 5000
```

according to https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-deploy-containers

Any idea what could have gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert on Azure, but looking at the log you posted many things changes comparing to the docker-compose you tested locally:
- redis is now mapped to 19446 instead of 6379
- containers don't run on the same network anymore (when start with docker-compose they are on the same network, but different docker run commands don't act the same way)

So the error you get might be due to miscommunication between the containers. Try to upload only your web app and access a static page. If that works then you should revisit how you connect to the redis container from your app.